# Why does a link with route set to posts.destroy in practice routes to posts.show

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <ul>
        @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <li>
            <a href="{{route('posts.show', $post->id)}}">
                {{$post->title}}
            </a>
            &emsp;
            <a href="{{route('posts.edit', $post->id)}}">
                Edit
            </a>
            &emsp;
            <a href="{{route('posts.destroy', $post->id)}}">
                Delete
            </a>
            @endforeach

    </ul>

@endsection
```

I am new to laravel and in the process of learning. In the code above i have made a simple Unordered list of posts that is in the database. Next to each post is a edit and delete links. The edit link works just fine and invokes edit method in posts controller. But the delete link doesn't work. I think it runs the show method instead of destroy method in posts controller. Why is this the case?

To be more clear i have already somewhat solved the problem with the code bellow inside the foreach directive

```
<form action="/posts/{{$post->id}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value=" DELETE">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" id="">
</form>
```

But why do this in the first place. I understand when we use form since a html form doesn't support DELETE method i had to add the hidden input. But why doesn't the hyper link tag work. This is the list of routes:
[image]

Comment: Could you share your routes?

Comment: @DanielPetrovaliev I have updated my question and included the list of routes.

Comment: Its because the hyperlink sends `Get` requests not `delete` request. So, when you send get request on `posts/{post}` it will trigger `posts.show`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links always perform GET method by default.

You can mimic DELETE method behavior using some javascript.